# MongoDB Time Series: Add secondary indexes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to add a secondary index to a MongoDb Time Series Collection - running on version **6.0.1** - to speed up queries;

My metaField and timeField are, respectively, "business_id" and "dt_op". I can successfully create a secondary index over them. However, as soon as I try to add the field "product_id" as index (composed by a string of 9 integers), with or without meta and time field, it throws the following error:

> Index build on collection failed due to the detection of mixed-schema data in the time-series buckets collection.
> Starting as of v5.2, time-series measurement bucketing has been
> modified to ensure that newly created time-series buckets do not
> contain mixed-schema data. For details, see:
> https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/

I check on the website and it clearly states:

> Time Series Secondary Indexes with MongoDB 6.0 and Later Starting in
> MongoDB 6.0, you can add a secondary index to any field.

How can I fix that and correctly create and index over "product_id"?

Answer (score 0):

Only properties of meta field is allowed to use as secondary indexes. Try declaring `product_id` as meta field and then index it.